# Issues running Tensorflow Object Detection on Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection

The command I am using to start the training process for my model is:

`python Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config --num_train_steps=2000`

And I am getting this error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 114, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 36, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 111, in main
    record_summaries=FLAGS.record_summaries)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 609, in train_loop
    train_input, unpad_groundtruth_tensors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 401, in load_fine_tune_checkpoint
    _ensure_model_is_built(model, input_dataset, unpad_groundtruth_tensors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 179, in _ensure_model_is_built
    labels,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 1312, in run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 2888, in call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_strategy.py", line 677, in _call_for_each_replica
    self._container_strategy(), fn, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_run.py", line 83, in call_for_each_replica
    return wrapped(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 55, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'ssd_mobile_net_v2_fpn_keras_feature_extractor/model/Conv1/Conv2D' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
      self._bootstrap_inner()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 171, in _dummy_computation_fn
      return _compute_losses_and_predictions_dicts(model, features, labels,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 124, in _compute_losses_and_predictions_dicts
      prediction_dict = model.predict(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 569, in predict
      if self._feature_extractor.is_keras_model:
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 570, in predict
      feature_maps = self._feature_extractor(preprocessed_inputs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 490, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 251, in call
      return self._extract_features(inputs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpn_keras_feature_extractor.py", line 219, in _extract_features
      image_features = self.classification_backbone(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 490, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 459, in call
      inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 596, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py", line 250, in call
      outputs = self.convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py", line 232, in convolution_op
      name=self.__class__.__name__)
Node: 'ssd_mobile_net_v2_fpn_keras_feature_extractor/model/Conv1/Conv2D'
DNN library is not found.
     [[{{node ssd_mobile_net_v2_fpn_keras_feature_extractor/model/Conv1/Conv2D}}]] [Op:__inference__dummy_computation_fn_15090]
```

I have double checked that my runtime/notebook settings that I am using the GPU as my hardware accelerator. I have also confirmed that the GPU has been found. Does anybody know how to fix this?

my current pip list is:

```
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ------------------------------
absl-py                       1.2.0
alabaster                     0.7.12
albumentations                0.1.12
altair                        4.2.0
apache-beam                   2.40.0
appdirs                       1.4.4
argon2-cffi                   21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings          21.2.0
arviz                         0.12.1
astor                         0.8.1
astropy                       4.3.1
astunparse                    1.6.3
atari-py                      0.2.9
atomicwrites                  1.4.1
attrs                         21.4.0
audioread                     2.1.9
autograd                      1.4
avro-python3                  1.10.2
Babel                         2.10.3
backcall                      0.2.0
beautifulsoup4                4.6.3
bleach                        5.0.1
blis                          0.7.8
bokeh                         2.3.3
branca                        0.5.0
bs4                           0.0.1
CacheControl                  0.12.11
cached-property               1.5.2
cachetools                    4.2.4
catalogue                     2.0.7
certifi                       2022.6.15
cffi                          1.15.1
cftime                        1.6.1
chardet                       3.0.4
charset-normalizer            2.1.0
click                         7.1.2
cloudpickle                   2.1.0
cmake                         3.22.5
cmdstanpy                     0.9.5
colorama                      0.4.5
colorcet                      3.0.0
colorlover                    0.3.0
community                     1.0.0b1
contextlib2                   0.5.5
convertdate                   2.4.0
coverage                      3.7.1
coveralls                     0.5
crcmod                        1.7
cufflinks                     0.17.3
cupy-cuda111                  9.4.0
cvxopt                        1.2.7
cvxpy                         1.0.31
cycler                        0.11.0
cymem                         2.0.6
Cython                        0.29.30
daft                          0.0.4
dask                          2.12.0
datascience                   0.10.6
debugpy                       1.0.0
decorator                     4.4.2
defusedxml                    0.7.1
deprecat                      2.1.1
descartes                     1.1.0
dill                          0.3.1.1
distributed                   1.25.3
dlib                          19.18.0+zzzcolab20220513001918
dm-tree                       0.1.7
docopt                        0.6.2
docutils                      0.17.1
dopamine-rl                   1.0.5
earthengine-api               0.1.317
easydict                      1.9
ecos                          2.0.10
editdistance                  0.5.3
en-core-web-sm                3.3.0
entrypoints                   0.4
ephem                         4.1.3
et-xmlfile                    1.1.0
etils                         0.6.0
fa2                           0.3.5
fastai                        2.7.7
fastavro                      1.5.3
fastcore                      1.5.6
fastdownload                  0.0.7
fastdtw                       0.3.4
fastjsonschema                2.16.1
fastprogress                  1.0.2
fastrlock                     0.8
fbprophet                     0.7.1
feather-format                0.4.1
filelock                      3.7.1
firebase-admin                4.4.0
fix-yahoo-finance             0.0.22
Flask                         1.1.4
flatbuffers                   1.12
folium                        0.8.3
future                        0.16.0
gast                          0.4.0
GDAL                          2.2.2
gdown                         4.4.0
gensim                        3.6.0
geographiclib                 1.52
geopy                         1.17.0
gin-config                    0.5.0
glob2                         0.7
google                        2.0.3
google-api-core               1.31.6
google-api-python-client      1.12.11
google-auth                   1.35.0
google-auth-httplib2          0.0.4
google-auth-oauthlib          0.4.6
google-cloud-bigquery         1.21.0
google-cloud-bigquery-storage 1.1.2
google-cloud-core             1.0.3
google-cloud-datastore        1.8.0
google-cloud-firestore        1.7.0
google-cloud-language         1.2.0
google-cloud-storage          1.18.1
google-cloud-translate        1.5.0
google-colab                  1.0.0
google-pasta                  0.2.0
google-resumable-media        0.4.1
googleapis-common-protos      1.56.4
googledrivedownloader         0.4
graphviz                      0.10.1
greenlet                      1.1.2
grpcio                        1.47.0
gspread                       3.4.2
gspread-dataframe             3.0.8
gym                           0.17.3
h5py                          3.1.0
hdfs                          2.7.0
HeapDict                      1.0.1
hijri-converter               2.2.4
holidays                      0.10.5.2
holoviews                     1.14.9
html5lib                      1.0.1
httpimport                    0.5.18
httplib2                      0.17.4
httplib2shim                  0.0.3
humanize                      0.5.1
hyperopt                      0.1.2
ideep4py                      2.0.0.post3
idna                          2.10
imageio                       2.4.1
imagesize                     1.4.1
imbalanced-learn              0.8.1
imblearn                      0.0
imgaug                        0.2.9
importlib-metadata            4.12.0
importlib-resources           5.8.0
imutils                       0.5.4
inflect                       2.1.0
iniconfig                     1.1.1
intel-openmp                  2022.1.0
intervaltree                  2.1.0
ipykernel                     4.10.1
ipython                       5.5.0
ipython-genutils              0.2.0
ipython-sql                   0.3.9
ipywidgets                    7.7.1
itsdangerous                  1.1.0
jax                           0.3.14
jaxlib                        0.3.14+cuda11.cudnn805
jedi                          0.18.1
jieba                         0.42.1
Jinja2                        2.11.3
joblib                        1.1.0
jpeg4py                       0.1.4
jsonschema                    4.3.3
jupyter                       1.0.0
jupyter-client                5.3.5
jupyter-console               5.2.0
jupyter-core                  4.11.1
jupyterlab-pygments           0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets            1.1.1
kaggle                        1.5.12
kapre                         0.3.7
keras                         2.9.0
Keras-Preprocessing           1.1.2
keras-vis                     0.4.1
kiwisolver                    1.4.4
korean-lunar-calendar         0.2.1
langcodes                     3.3.0
libclang                      14.0.1
librosa                       0.8.1
lightgbm                      2.2.3
llvmlite                      0.34.0
lmdb                          0.99
LunarCalendar                 0.0.9
lvis                          0.5.3
lxml                          4.2.6
Markdown                      3.4.1
MarkupSafe                    2.0.1
matplotlib                    3.2.2
matplotlib-inline             0.1.3
matplotlib-venn               0.11.7
missingno                     0.5.1
mistune                       0.8.4
mizani                        0.6.0
mkl                           2019.0
mlxtend                       0.14.0
more-itertools                8.13.0
moviepy                       0.2.3.5
mpmath                        1.2.1
msgpack                       1.0.4
multiprocess                  0.70.13
multitasking                  0.0.11
murmurhash                    1.0.7
music21                       5.5.0
natsort                       5.5.0
nbclient                      0.6.6
nbconvert                     5.6.1
nbformat                      5.4.0
nest-asyncio                  1.5.5
netCDF4                       1.6.0
networkx                      2.6.3
nibabel                       3.0.2
nltk                          3.7
notebook                      5.3.1
numba                         0.51.2
numexpr                       2.8.3
numpy                         1.21.6
oauth2client                  4.1.3
oauthlib                      3.2.0
object-detection              0.1
okgrade                       0.4.3
opencv-contrib-python         4.6.0.66
opencv-python                 4.6.0.66
opencv-python-headless        4.6.0.66
openpyxl                      3.0.10
opt-einsum                    3.3.0
orjson                        3.7.8
osqp                          0.6.2.post0
packaging                     21.3
palettable                    3.3.0
pandas                        1.3.5
pandas-datareader             0.9.0
pandas-gbq                    0.13.3
pandas-profiling              1.4.1
pandocfilters                 1.5.0
panel                         0.12.1
param                         1.12.2
parso                         0.8.3
pathlib                       1.0.1
pathy                         0.6.2
patsy                         0.5.2
pep517                        0.12.0
pexpect                       4.8.0
pickleshare                   0.7.5
Pillow                        7.1.2
pip                           21.1.3
pip-tools                     6.2.0
plotly                        5.5.0
plotnine                      0.6.0
pluggy                        0.7.1
pooch                         1.6.0
portalocker                   2.5.1
portpicker                    1.3.9
prefetch-generator            1.0.1
preshed                       3.0.6
prettytable                   3.3.0
progressbar2                  3.38.0
prometheus-client             0.14.1
promise                       2.3
prompt-toolkit                1.0.18
proto-plus                    1.20.6
protobuf                      3.19.4
psutil                        5.4.8
psycopg2                      2.7.6.1
ptyprocess                    0.7.0
py                            1.11.0
py-cpuinfo                    8.0.0
pyarrow                       6.0.1
pyasn1                        0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                0.2.8
pycocotools                   2.0.4
pycparser                     2.21
pyct                          0.4.8
pydantic                      1.8.2
pydata-google-auth            1.4.0
pydot                         1.3.0
pydot-ng                      2.0.0
pydotplus                     2.0.2
PyDrive                       1.3.1
pyemd                         0.5.1
pyerfa                        2.0.0.1
pyglet                        1.5.0
Pygments                      2.6.1
pygobject                     3.26.1
pymc3                         3.11.5
PyMeeus                       0.5.11
pymongo                       3.12.3
pymystem3                     0.2.0
PyOpenGL                      3.1.6
pyparsing                     2.4.7
pyrsistent                    0.18.1
pysndfile                     1.3.8
PySocks                       1.7.1
pystan                        2.19.1.1
pytest                        3.6.4
python-apt                    0.0.0
python-chess                  0.23.11
python-dateutil               2.8.2
python-louvain                0.16
python-slugify                6.1.2
python-utils                  3.3.3
pytz                          2022.1
pyviz-comms                   2.2.0
PyWavelets                    1.3.0
PyYAML                        5.4.1
pyzmq                         23.2.0
qdldl                         0.1.5.post2
qtconsole                     5.3.1
QtPy                          2.1.0
regex                         2022.6.2
requests                      2.28.1
requests-oauthlib             1.3.1
resampy                       0.3.1
rpy2                          3.4.5
rsa                           4.8
sacrebleu                     2.1.0
scikit-image                  0.18.3
scikit-learn                  1.0.2
scipy                         1.7.3
screen-resolution-extra       0.0.0
scs                           3.2.0
seaborn                       0.11.2
semver                        2.13.0
Send2Trash                    1.8.0
sentencepiece                 0.1.96
seqeval                       1.2.2
setuptools                    57.4.0
setuptools-git                1.2
Shapely                       1.8.2
simplegeneric                 0.8.1
six                           1.15.0
sklearn                       0.0
sklearn-pandas                1.8.0
smart-open                    5.2.1
snowballstemmer               2.2.0
sortedcontainers              2.4.0
SoundFile                     0.10.3.post1
soupsieve                     2.3.2.post1
spacy                         3.3.1
spacy-legacy                  3.0.9
spacy-loggers                 1.0.3
Sphinx                        1.8.6
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5
sphinxcontrib-websupport      1.2.4
SQLAlchemy                    1.4.39
sqlparse                      0.4.2
srsly                         2.4.3
statsmodels                   0.10.2
sympy                         1.7.1
tables                        3.7.0
tabulate                      0.8.10
tblib                         1.7.0
tenacity                      8.0.1
tensorboard                   2.9.1
tensorboard-data-server       0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1
tensorflow                    2.9.1
tensorflow-addons             0.17.1
tensorflow-datasets           4.0.1
tensorflow-estimator          2.9.0
tensorflow-gcs-config         2.8.0
tensorflow-gpu                2.9.1
tensorflow-hub                0.12.0
tensorflow-io                 0.26.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.26.0
tensorflow-metadata           1.9.0
tensorflow-model-optimization 0.7.3
tensorflow-probability        0.16.0
tensorflow-text               2.9.0
termcolor                     1.1.0
terminado                     0.13.3
testpath                      0.6.0
text-unidecode                1.3
textblob                      0.15.3
tf-models-official            2.9.2
tf-slim                       1.1.0
Theano-PyMC                   1.1.2
thinc                         8.0.17
threadpoolctl                 3.1.0
tifffile                      2021.11.2
tinycss2                      1.1.1
tomli                         2.0.1
toolz                         0.12.0
torch                         1.12.0+cu113
torchaudio                    0.12.0+cu113
torchsummary                  1.5.1
torchtext                     0.13.0
torchvision                   0.13.0+cu113
tornado                       5.1.1
tqdm                          4.64.0
traitlets                     5.1.1
tweepy                        3.10.0
typeguard                     2.7.1
typer                         0.4.2
typing-extensions             4.1.1
tzlocal                       1.5.1
uritemplate                   3.0.1
urllib3                       1.24.3
vega-datasets                 0.9.0
wasabi                        0.9.1
wcwidth                       0.2.5
webencodings                  0.5.1
Werkzeug                      1.0.1
wheel                         0.37.1
widgetsnbextension            3.6.1
wordcloud                     1.5.0
wrapt                         1.14.1
xarray                        0.20.2
xarray-einstats               0.2.2
xgboost                       0.90
xkit                          0.0.0
xlrd                          1.1.0
xlwt                          1.3.0
yellowbrick                   1.4
zict                          2.2.0
zipp                          3.8.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out. I added

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.8
!apt install --allow-change-held-packages libcudnn8=8.1.0.77-1+cuda11.2
```

before running the training command and it resolved the issue.